# 'str' object is not callable and sep operator

Tags: python

Compiler says TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when trying to execute program. What does this mean and how do I remedy the problem? Also I'm trying to use sep but it returns an error for that too. Code will follow. Thank you for all recommendations

```
class dog:

    def __init__(self, name, breed, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.owner = owner

    def bark(self):
        print(self.name, "barks.")

    def breed(self):
        print(self.name, "is a", self.breed)

    def owner(self):
        print(self.name, "'s owner is ", self.owner, sep='')

d1 = dog("Tommy", "Terrier", "Mary")
d1.bark()
d1.breed()
d1.owner()


d2 = dog("Johnny", "Bloodhound", "Alex")
d2.bark()
d2.breed()
d2.owner()
```

Edit: Thank you Simon for solution.
Updated code:

```
class dog:

def __init__(self, name, breed, owner):
    self.name = name
    self.breed = breed
    self.owner = owner

def speak(self):
    print(self.name, "barks.")

def identify(self):
    print(self.name, "is a", self.breed)

def relation(self):
    print(self.name, "belongs to", self.owner)

d1 = dog("Tommy", "Terrier", "Mary")
d1.speak()
d1.identify()
d1.relation()


d2 = dog("Johnny", "Bloodhound", "Alex")
d2.speak()
d2.identify()
d2.relation()
```

This is working as intended, however it's printing weird. This is the output I'm getting:

```
('Tommy', 'barks.')
('Tommy', 'is a', 'Terrier')
('Tommy', 'belongs to', 'Mary')
('Johnny', 'barks.')
('Johnny', 'is a', 'Bloodhound')
('Johnny', 'belongs to', 'Alex')
```

Any idea how I can strip the parentheses etc.?

Comment: Don't call your data attributes the same thing as your methods.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because you called the variables the same as the functions. To fix this you would just need to change the name of either the functions or the variables.  For example:

```
class dog:

    def __init__(self, name, breed, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.owner = owner

    def bark(self):
        print(self.name, "barks.")

    def breeds(self):
        print(self.name, "is a", self.breed)

    def owners(self):
        print(self.name, "'s owner is ", self.owner, sep='')

d1 = dog("Tommy", "Terrier", "Mary")
d1.bark()
d1.breeds()
d1.owners()


d2 = dog("Johnny", "Bloodhound", "Alex")
d2.bark()
d2.breeds()
d2.owners()
```

In your code Python thinks you are calling the variable (`self.breed` or `self.owner`) not the functions (`self.breed`, `self.owners`) since both are defined in the same way.  It cannot distinguish between the two and just takes the first it finds (i.e the variables). Which returns an error.

You could reproduce the callable error in simple terms like this:

```
breed = "BloodHound"
breed()
```

Which is exactly what you are doing above.